# C while loop between number range

Tags: microcontroller, c

How do I set up a while loop to loop if a variable is between a range? For example if a number is <100 or >1500 than loop. I tried the below but it didn't work...

```
while (number < 100 || number > 1500);
```

Comment: (1) This is purely a C language question. It has too little to do with electronics design.  (2) Do yourself a favor and learn C.  Like...  you know... actually learn it.

Comment: for purely software-related questions, there would be a separate portal (say lke http://physics.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/) . that will help us to sort the informations.

Comment: Once i've seen in C-programing , it give-out wrong answer if the values are bigger than a certain.

Comment: A couple of intermediate boolean vars would have sorted this issue and made any sbsequent debugging easier.  Why are people so bad at debugging?   Just simplify stuff and the problem often becomes clear!

Comment: while ((number <100) || (number >1500))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditions in programming don't work like in math. Every comparison like that returns a true or false value. If you need the number to be in a certain range you have to set up 2 conditions: `number <= max` and `number >= min`. Now you will have two bool outputs but you need to combine them into one. '&&' operator is used to do that. The final statement will look like: `(number <= max && number >= min)`. That will return true when both above values are true. ( `<=` and `>=` will return true if the left value is smaller/larger or equal)

I'd suggest posting programming related questions on stackoverflow instead next time, which is focused on programming and software engineering.

Comment: You have the = and < reversed in the comparison operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool belowLowLimit = number<100;
bool aboveHighLimit = number>1500;

while(belowLowLimit || aboveHighLimit){doSuff};
```

See how easy it is when you don't try and write 'clever' code?  Note how a break on the while() line would allow the easy inspection of the two bools.  Also, note how you don't really need to comment or document this code.

If you want to do something complex, don't.  Just split it up.

Divide and conquer, without needing SO:).

[at least you named your var 'number' and not just 'n', though we dont really know what 'number' represents.  'userInputVal', for example, would have been better]

Comment: The bool's will have to be recalculated every time inside the while loop, as `number` changes inside the loop.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje sure, yes, but OP's question had an empty loop, so, I thought, WTH.. :)